# Managing users and profiles in Rails

Tags: beginner, ruby, ruby-on-rails, active-record, helper

I am building a Rails marketplace application using TDD. I would like to get advice on the way in which I have built the `User` associated `Profile` associations and way in which these are then handled in the controllers.

#### User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :listings, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :watches, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :watched_listings,  -> { uniq }, :through => :watches, dependent: :destroy

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:

  acts_as_messageable

  def mailboxer_email(object)
    email
  end

  def self.search(search)
    where("email ILIKE ?", "%#{search}%") 
  end

  after_create :build_profile

end
```

#### Profile model

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

#### Users controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.all
    if params[:search]
      @users = User.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")
    else
      @users = User.all.order('created_at DESC')
    end
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def watchlist
    @watched_listings = current_user.watched_listings.all
  end
end
```

### Profiles controller

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only [:edit, :update]
  before_filter :correct_user, :only [:edit, :update]

  def show
    @profile = Profile.find_by(user_id: params[:user_id])
  end

  def edit
    @profile = Profile.find_by user_id: current_user.id
  end

  def update
    @profile = Profile.find_by user_id: current_user.id
    if @profile.update(profile_params)
      flash[:notices] = ["Your profile was successfully updated"]
      render 'show'
    else
      flash[:notices] = ["Your profile could not be updated"]
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  private

  def profile_params
    params.require(:profile).permit(:city, :country, :avatar)
  end

  def correct_user
    @profile = Profile.find_by(user_id: params[:user_id])
    redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user?(@profile)
  end
end
```

I have also defined:

#### Profiles helper

```
module ProfilesHelper
  def current_user?(user)
    user == current_user
  end
end
```

#### Within my Application Controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    edit_user_profile_path(resource)
  end

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    edit_user_profile_path(resource)
  end
end
```

I'm very keen to get any feedback on:

- If the use of the `after_create :build_profile` is appropriate. Does this violate SRP principles by making the user model responsible for the creation of a profile?
- The best way to validate the correct user in the profile controller - to enforce whether a user can edit a profile or not.
- Mainly whether it is required that I be finding profiles by `Profile.find_by(user_id: params[:user_id])` rather than by a `Profile` ID.
- Any other improvements to the code!

I have RSpec and Capybara tests to back this [here](https://github.com/benhawker/rails_marketplace/tree/5fab8cb9bcc6e9a7baeec33c37b30b05117e87d0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my thoughts.

## Profile Model

I'm not sure that the separate profile is pulling enough weight to justify its existence. It seems that a lot of this code could be avoided by collapsing it into the User model. I appreciate that the `User` and `Profile` can be two separate entities but it looks like it'll be much easier to keep them in one model until they grow too large to be viable, or there comes a time when a `Profile` has a separate lifecycle from a `User`.

Which then avoids your question around SRP altogether :)

But if we were to keep them separate, I don't think it would be a practical violation of SRP because your application likely depends on a profile always existing for a user. So having asserted that `User` should always have a `Profile`, you are then faced with the choice of leaving the creation in the hands of the controller, or the model. I favour leaving it in the hands of the model because the model is responsible for modelling the relationships between different business objects.

## Finding the Profile and Validating Access

You could replace the find methods with a `before_action` that uses the user's relationship with the profile like so:

```
before_action :get_profile, only: [:edit, :update]

def get_profile
   @profile = current_user.profile
end
```

This will both reduce the amount of code required to select the profile, and ensure that the user can only access their profile to edit/update it.

However, at that point it doesn't make sense to have the profile edit and update actions available with a user ID. They're essentially now singular resources and should be handled accordingly in your routes.

You ask whether find by `user_id` or not is a good choice. It depends on whether the person accessing that route will be accessing it from the context of its `User`, or the `Profile` owner.

## current_user?

I don't believe this code will work. You are passing it only `Profile` objects, and comparing it to the `current_user` method which returns a `User` object (or `null` if not logged in, if memory serves). This should always return `false`. You either need to call `profile.user` before passing it to the method, or have that method make the call.

Comment: Thanks Richard for taking the time to write this feedback so clearly. I too had an uneasy feeling about the user profile association - going to refactor this back into the user model this weekend and try to tidy it up. Your point about wrapping the find methods with a before action will go along way to cleaning up my controllers in future Rails project.

Comment: I'm glad you found it useful! Cheers :)

Comment: Also, listen to your gut. Every time I've ignored the uneasy feeling I've had to come back to it later at much higher cost. It's really just your subconscious trying to avoid work it doesn't want right now.